# Conditions for not being a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

> I have a subspace $S$ and a vector set $V$, on what conditions is $V$ **not** a basis for $S$?

I know to be a basis, $\text{span } V = S$ **and** $V$ must be linearly independent.

So to **not** be a basis for $S$, $V$ must be either linearly dependent or $\text{span } V \ne S$.

**Question:** Say $V$ is linearly dependent (hence not a basis), could $\text{span } V = S$, still be a possibility?

Comment: Yes, in fact if $B$ is a basis, let $V = B \cup \{0\}$. Then $V$'s span is $S$ but $V$ is not a basis.

Comment: The conditions for $V$ to not be a basis for $S$, is either that it is linearly independent, or that it doesn't have the same cardinality as the dimension of $S$ (if it is finite). The answer can sometimes be specific to $S$ and $V$, For example, see the Muntz- Szasz theorem, that tells you **exactly** when a set of powers of $x$ span $C[0,1]$ with uniform norm,

Comment: @OpenBall - simpler example: Let $V = S$.